# How to reuse a command function discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a music bot that streams radio and each stream is a command for ease of use. The problem is that there are 100+ stations now and it's getting increasingly more difficult to update the code for each one.

````
@bot.command(aliases=["VAR1", "VAR2"])
@commands.check(if_channel_private)
async def VAR(ctx):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    station = 'VAR3'
    if len(embed_history.fields) <= 4:
        embed_history.add_field(inline=False, name=f"[{current_time}] Played:", value=f'`{station}`')
    elif len(embed_history.fields) > 4:
        embed_history.remove_field(0)
        embed_history.add_field(inline=False, name=f"[{current_time}] Played:", value=f'`{station}`')
    stream = 'URL VAR4'
    resume = stream
    if len(pause_list) != 0 or len(radio_station) != 0:
        pause_list.clear()
        radio_station.clear()
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()
    try:
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(stream))
        print(f'Playing {station}')
    except:
        print(f"An error occurred while trying to play {station}")
        await ctx.send(error_message)
    radio_station.append(station)
    pause_list.append(resume)
    embed_st.clear_fields()
    embed_st.add_field(inline=False, name=embed_name,
                       value="VAR5")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed_st)

@VAR.error
async def _pr_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        if ctx.message.author.voice is None:
            return
        await ctx.send(f"Only users in __the same private voice channel__ can change the station!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"```css\n"
                       "[ERROR: Unexpected error has occured!]"
                       "```")
        print(error)
````

This is how it looks like for each station. Is it possible to write this only once and then call it for every station? And only to have to change the variables (VAR)? Otherwise, it bloats the whole text file with repetitive code...

Answer (score 1):

I don't check this code, but may be it's work. Create function, and send to it your variables `station` and `stream`:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["VAR", "VAR"])
@commands.check(if_channel_private)
async def VAR(ctx):
    await some_function('VAR', 'URL_VAR')


# Your function for all stations
async def some_function(station, stream):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if len(embed_history.fields) <= 4:
        embed_history.add_field(inline=False, name=f"[{current_time}] Played:", value=f'`{station}`')
    elif len(embed_history.fields) > 4:
        embed_history.remove_field(0)
        embed_history.add_field(inline=False, name=f"[{current_time}] Played:", value=f'`{station}`')
    resume = stream
    if len(pause_list) != 0 or len(radio_station) != 0:
        pause_list.clear()
        radio_station.clear()
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()
    try:
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(stream))
        print(f'Playing {station}')
    except:
        print(f"An error occurred while trying to play {station}")
        await ctx.send(error_message)
    radio_station.append(station)
    pause_list.append(resume)
    embed_st.clear_fields()
    embed_st.add_field(inline=False, name=embed_name,
                       value="VAR")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed_st)
```